# Python-merge. Причина некорректной работы merge

Tags: python, pandas

Условно объединяю два датафрэйма в одном из которых 5 000 строк, в другом 2 910
На выходе получаю датафрейм с 17 077 строк. 
В чем может быть причина? 
В ключе? 
объединяла по on='inner', on='left'
Все способы на выходе дают большее количество строк

Comment: У `pandas`, что ли??

Comment: Да, именно.....Раннее с такой проблемой не сталкивалась

Answer (score 3):

Скорее всего, значения в ключевых столбцах у вас не уникальные. Например, если в первом датафрейме есть неуникальное значение, которое встречается два раза, а во втором - такое же значение, которое встречается пять раз, то после мерджа с этим ключом получится десять строк (2*5).